# Proof that Variation of Integral is Equal to Integral of the Variation

Tags: calculus

I need to proof that $$\delta(\int_a^b f(x)dx)=\int_a^b\delta f(x)dx$$

I actually dont know how to proceed. Can I use the 
Leibniz integral rule as an example for the derivation ? In that case he is using $$d/dx$$ but we have $$\delta$$ so I am not sure I can use that proof.

Any help. Thanks

The variation comes from the calculus of variation. For a given path the extremum occcurs on $$\delta I=\delta \int_{x_1}^{x_2}f (y,y';x) dx=0$$

Comment: I edited my post. Yes its definite integral. I am not sure it can or not

Comment: as far as I know the (first) variation $\delta$ of a function is equivalent to the Gateaux derivative. However if your integral is definite then the variation of it makes no so much sense, because the Gateaux derivative of a constant is zero

Comment: @Masacroso Then how I can proof this ? Its zero yes but this step is also important

Comment: the question,as stated, doesnt make sense to my eyes. Suppose that $f$ is differentiable, then $\delta f(x)=\partial f(x)$, that is, it first derivation and it derivative coincides, but taking $f(x):=x^2$ then you have that $0=\int_a^b f'(x)\, dx=b^2-a^2$ what is not true in general. You need to context your exercise, what is $f$ here exactly?

Comment: @Masacroso We dont know the $f$.Its just a function. I just copied the question without making any changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For *variation of a function[al]* we typically mean the small change in its value due to a class of variations of the argument. Hence, we must first agree on what is the varying argument here (and even how it is supposed to vary).
For example, the first equality you propose holds if you are interested in the variation of the definite integral for varying $f$ (called the dependent variable, for simplicity):
$$\delta \int \limits_{a}^{b}f(x)\mathrm{d}x=\int \limits _a^b\left(f(x)+\delta f(x)\right)\mathrm{d}x-\int \limits _a^bf(x)\mathrm{d}x=\int \limits _a^b\delta f(x)\mathrm{d}x\ .$$
On the other hand, a different form of the variation of the integral is obtained if the varying quantity is related to the independent variable, i.e. the extrema of integration.

Typically (but not always), in the calculus of variations we are interested in analysing the change a definite integral is subjected to when the dependent variables change. In these cases, it is true that for a continuous function $F$ $$\delta \int \limits_a^bF(x,y,y')\mathrm{d}x=\int \limits _a^b \delta F(x,y,y')\mathrm{d}x\ ,$$ where $\delta F=\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\delta y+\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}\delta y'$.